# How to setup VLAN on Android?

Tags: usb, networking

Can anybody give me idea how to setup the [VLAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vlan) on android. I get VLAN 200 tagged traffic from some device. So how can I configure or setup the networking stuffs in android to allow traffic tagged with VLAN 200.

Currently, I can access normal traffic (without any VLAN) on mini usb port.